# Difference between user.isinrole and IsInRoleAsync(TUser user, string role)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am from a MVC background and Have just started working on ASP.Net Core. I am using Identity for Authentication.

For Authorization, In MVC I used to use:

```
if(User.IsInRole("TestRole"))
```

In .Net Core, it seems like :

```
if(await IsInRoleAsync(User,"TestRole"))
```

From my initial impressions, It looks like MVC used to check in the claims where as Core checks from the database every single time. Am I correct in my assumption and that there is a DB trip every time the method is called in Core?

If it is checking from the DB every time, would it not be an expensive operation and how is it any beneficial from the claims check?

Comment: Why don't you just check? It's open source for a reason: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs#L412 (note: this is if you are using the Entity Framework package, you can roll your own)

Comment: What is `IsInRoleAsync`? Is that a method in your code? Shouldn't you be able to figure out what it is doing?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto To be fair, I wouldn't expect most developers to go digging around in Github code. In fact, I bet many devs aren't even aware that it's open source.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sorry, but if everybody would check themselves the official documentation of everything and also the source code of open source repos, what point would it make for StackOverflow to exist?

Comment: @meJustAndrew There are plenty of programming questions not answered by checking the documentation.  SO's rules specifically expects people to be doing research before asking their questions.  It doesn't exist to just reproduce readily accessible documentation.  SO exists to answer questions *not* answerable with a reasonable research effort.

Comment: @Servy with all the respect, I really believe that *a reasonable research effort* is something very broad. In this case specifically, getting the answer from SO could be much easier for everybody rather than checking the open source repository.

Comment: @meJustAndrew Then say that.  Don't say that people shouldn't even bother to read the documentation and that this site exists just to repeat such information.

Answer (score 1):

Identity now relies on the implementation by the `UserStore<TUser>` assigned to the `UserManager<TUser>` in use. If you use the Entity Framework package, the `UserStore<TUser>` implementation always checks against the database.

You can create your own `UserStore<TUser>` and check against the `Controller.User`'s `Claims` property or even perform some sort of caching after getting the claims the first time. It's up to you what you use and how you cache/refresh those values.

Notice that the previous implementations performed a synchronous database call if the Claims weren't already retrieved, so you should be thankful it now is `IsInRoleAsync`.

Answer (score -2):

[From the Source Code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs) you can see that It is using `DbSet`

```
public TContext Context { get; private set; }

private DbSet<TUser> UsersSet { get { return Context.Set<TUser>(); } }
private DbSet<TRole> Roles { get { return Context.Set<TRole>(); } }
private DbSet<TUserClaim> UserClaims { get { return Context.Set<TUserClaim>(); } }
private DbSet<TUserRole> UserRoles { get { return Context.Set<TUserRole>(); } }
private DbSet<TUserLogin> UserLogins { get { return Context.Set<TUserLogin>(); } }
private DbSet<TUserToken> UserTokens { get { return Context.Set<TUserToken>(); } }
```

Comment: *where as Core checks from the database every single time.* The answer is yes, It uses DbSet to get result from DB

Comment: That'snot the documentation, that's source code. It's also the source for **one** implementation which you don't have to use